# Kohana 3.2 - Get referrer URI

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, referrer

I'm attempting to get the referrer URI in Kohana 3.2 using the following code:

```
$referrer = $this->request->referrer();
var_dump($referrer);
```

However the function returns NULL, I'm expecting it to return the page I left to get to this one.

Is that how it should work... and if so what am I missing or doing wrong?

This is being run in the Controller.

Documentation here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#referrer

Comment: Does your Controller extend Controller_Template? If not, it won't have access to `$this->request`

Comment: It extends my own controller template and I can access $this->request.

Comment: And does that extend the Kohana core Controller_Template? :)

Comment: Yes it does, I can access $this->request.

Comment: The referrer is the URL of the previous webpage from which a **link was followed**, not just _the page I left to get to this one_. Do you come from the clicked link?

Comment: Kind of.... my Kohana setup goes through a routeHandler class. So it goes through that first... and then to the actual page that the anchor linked to.

Comment: OK, the other potential thing is that your browser may be set up to not send a referrer. Have you tried it in another browser, or just the one?

Comment: I think I see whats happening... the referrer is there when the routeHandler is first called... but not there on the actual page load.

Comment: Ah I fixed it... will post answer in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I was having was cause by the way my Kohana system is setup. Basically I have a routeHandler in the middle of my system which controls the routes users take. In that script a new request was generated and then executed.

What was happening was when creating the new request object it wasn't having the referrer uri added to it. I have added the following code and now I am able to get the referring uri from the controller at the end of the routing process.

```
$referrer = $this->request->referrer();
$request = new Request($uri);
$request->referrer($referrer);

echo $request->execute()
             ->send_headers()
             ->body();
```

Alternatively a cleaner more native solution as suggested by [atma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215926/atma) is the following:

```
Request::initial()->referrer()
```

Comment: Why you do not do it in kohana way? `Request::initial()->referrer()` - an easy way for reach the initial request from subrequest that contain referrer.

Comment: Didn't know about getting it that way. Tried it and it works. So now we have two solutions. =D

Comment: @atma I suggest you put it as an answer not a comment, so people can upvote it and diggersworld can possibly accept it if he finds it better than his solution.

Comment: @Michal M I do not want to duplicate replies. In this answer there are two solutions, both works well so diggersworld can accept it if he want.